# Insert row in an Excel table

Tags: excel, apache, apache-poi, row

I have this Excel file:

[image: Excel Table]

I want to simulate with Apache POI, the excel operations "Insert Row" for the table. 
Table style (alternating color rows) should also be maintained.

With:

```
sheet.shiftRows(10, rowCount, size);
sheet.createRow(1);
```

The style of the table is not maintained, because the row is outside the table.

How can I maintain the style?

Comment: Which version of POI are you using? There have been some fixes in recent versions...

Comment: @centic version 3.12

Comment: Can you verify it it still happens with the latest available version, i.e. 3.17-beta1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by rewriting a new excel file and including all the rows in a new table.